# how to remove / hide plugin button that sits in the wordpress admin top bar

Tags: wordpress

Hiall,
I have a plugin that has a button in the top adminbar in the admin section of wordpress right next to the edit button which is really annoying. 
How do I go about hiding this plugins button or removing this option from the wp admin menu bar itself?

In css I can see the buttons id. It is

wp-admin-bar-plugin_name_admin_bar

The button actually doesn't have a link when I hover it but it does show a popup menu.

When I look in the plugins functions.php file I can see where it is adding itself to the admin section.

```
// Create our custom menu in the admin bar.
    function fts_admin_bar_menu() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        if ( !is_super_admin() || !is_admin_bar_showing() )
            return;
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'plugin_admin_bar',
        'title' => __( 'Plugin Name', 'plugin-name'),
        'href' => FALSE ) );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'plugin_cache',
        'parent' => 'plugin_admin_bar',
        'title' => __( 'Clear Cache', 'plugin-name'),
        'href' => '#' ) );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'plugin_admin_bar_settings',
        'parent' => 'plugin_admin_bar',
        'title' => __( 'Settings', 'plugin-name'),
        'href' => admin_url( 'admin.php?page=plugin-settings-page') ) );
    }
}//END Class
```

I obviously don't want to be manually hacking this plugins core file, but rather some how exclude it's menu item using my own themes function file.

If anyone can show me how I do this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Use [remove_menu()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu) with the ID in your own functions.php file.

The function should be used with the admin_bar_menu hook. [See also](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `remove_node()` function. The wordpress codex has a really good explanation on how to achieve this.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node